# Python Tweepy Bot that randomly tweets image and a corresponding text caption

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

I am trying to make a Tweepy bot which randomly selects an image from a folder and tweets it with a corresponding caption from a text file, and repeats this on a set interval via sleep. I have not used python or any other coding language before so I am extremely unacquainted with how to accomplish this. So far I have this:

```
import tweepy
from time import sleep
import random

print('Twitter Bot')

CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXXXXX'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXXXXX'
ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXXX'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'XXXXXXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

filename = open('tweets.txt','r')
file_lines = filename.readlines()
filename.close()

media_list = list()
response = api.media_upload('image.png')
media_list.append(response.media_id_string)

randomChoice = random.randrange(len(file_lines))
print (file_lines[randomChoice])
api.update_status(status=file_lines[randomChoice], media_ids=media_list)
```

As you can see all this does is select a random line as the tweet text, and a set image. However, I am trying to achieve either selecting a random image with corresponding text, or vice versa. That is: there should be a specific text line corresponding to each image, but I'm unsure how to go about this.

Comment: Maybe try store information in a JSON file ? For example `[{"text":"hi", "image":"/image1.jpg"}]`

Comment: @Frank How would I go about having the script process and tweet using that? Sorry to bother, I'm extremely unacquainted with coding.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store your information in a `.json` file like this:

```js
[
  {
    "text": "hi",
    "image": "/image1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "text": "hello",
    "image": "/image2.jpg"
  }
]
```

Then load it in Python as a list:

```
import json
with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    info = json.load(f)
```

And then the rest is just same as your code: random choose an item from the loaded list.